# Run Selenium test in Docker container

Tags: python, selenium, docker, testing, pytest

I have a task to run Python selenium tests in docker.
First of all I run Selenium grid with docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-gold
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    ports:
     - 4577
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    ports:
     - 4578
```

Then I build container where I install pytest and copy my test framework

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.8
COPY . . 

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# update apk repo
RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# install chromedriver
RUN apk update
RUN apk add chromium chromium-chromedriver

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium==3.13.0
```

Then I tried to run my test file inside container:

```
docker run 3ae7b37d8a7f pytest tests/basic_smoke_test.py --browser docker -v
```

A a result I see network error:

> urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Address not
>   available>

Comment: That looks like a Python error...please show us your test code `basic_smoke_test.py`

Comment: Locally test run without problem.

Comment: This I use for run webdriver in docker:
 driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
                                      desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome'}

Comment: Full log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/du4w29w9hqkvrqd/logs.rtf?dl=0